# Выдает в прямом смысле код на странице, вместо его исполнения

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть код:

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    if ($(".sent_1") == "right") {
      $(".sent_1").animate({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
    if ($(".sent_2") == "wrong") {
      $(".sent_2").animate({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
    if ($(".sent_3") == "wrong") {
      $(".sent_3").animate({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/textcolors.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="ContentType" content="text/html">
  <title>Выполните задания</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="textcolors.js">
    <div class="exercise_sentences">
      <label for='first' class="sent_1">first(+)</label>
      <input type="text" name="fi">

      <label for='second' class="sent_2">second(-)</label>
      <input type="text" name="se">

      <label for='third' class="sent_3">third(-)</label>
      <input type="text" name="th">

      <input class="button" type="submit" name="check" value="Проверить">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку, хочу, чтобы при правильном ответе текст горел зеленым, а при не правильном - красным. Когда нажимаю кнопку - выдает просто текст ровно тот же что в textcolors.js, вместо того, чтобы выполнить его. (Подключал jQuery путем копипаста в jquery-3.0.0.min.js соотв версии.) Мне хотя бы узнать - что не так?

Comment: `if ($(".sent_1") == "right")` что вы тут проверяете? Что с чем сравниваете? Зачем в теге формы пишете `action="textcolors.js"`?

Comment: другого варианта как сделать чтобы при правильном ответе текст горел зеленым, а при не правильном - красным я не вижу. ($(".sent_1") == "right") - это если введено в поле слово right то текст бы горел зеленым. и тпВ теге формы пишу js потому что хочу, чтобы при нажатии кнопки выполнялся код js, который и подсвечивал бы данные при определенных условиях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример рабочего кода. В `action` пишут не ссылку на код, который должен выполниться, а ссылку на "серверный" файл, которому будут переданы данные. Обычно это php файл.

В теге `label` в атрибуте `for` нужно указать ссылку на `id` поля ввода, т.е. они должны совпадать.

Чтобы узнать значение поля на jq нужно применять метод `val()`.

JQ не будет анимировать нечисловые значения. Писать `color: red` некорректно.

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("input[name='first']").val() === "right") {
      $(".sent_1").css("color", "red");
    }
    if ($("input[name='second']").val() === "wrong") {
      $(".sent_2").css("color", "red");
    }
    if ($("input[name='third']").val() === "wrong") {
      $(".sent_3").css("color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="ContentType" content="text/html">
  <title>Выполните задания</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="exercise_sentences">
      <label for='first' class="sent_1">first(+)</label>
      <input type="text" id="first" name="first">

      <label for='second' class="sent_2">second(-)</label>
      <input type="text" id="second" name="second">

      <label for='third' class="sent_3">third(-)</label>
      <input type="text" id="third" name="third">

      <input class="button" type="button" name="check" value="Проверить">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Во первых, уберите JS файл из action формы, в принципе форма не нужна, раз вы не передаете данных на сервер. Во вторых, вы обращаетесь к классу по событию клика, пропустили точку перед button. В третьих для получения данных из формы вам надо присвоить класс или id input из которых вы получаете данные и использовать `$(".class").val()`. В четвертых, animate в JQ на сколько мне известно нет, есть в плагинах, можете использовать встроенные функции css например `$('.class').css({'border-color': 'red'});`

Comment: Дак нужна форма или нет? Вы сначала сказали что форма не нужна, а затем "для получения данных из формы"

Comment: В общем - как сказать html чтобы после нажатия кнопки адресовал это .js файлу, если через form action нельзя? (я привык при подключении php так делать, думал и js так же)

Comment: Все верно, но `animate` в jq есть по дефолту

Comment: Нет <form></form> не требуется